# opa (opalang) packages and imports

Tags: opa

so Im learning opa in my free time, and I have a question regarding packages/imports.

so Im declaring a few modules, in different files
package_a with module_A - in file1.opa
package_a with module_B - in file1.opa
package_b with module_C - in file2.opa

Which command line syntax (or sequence of commands) would I use to compile this project, if file1.opa is the main file? "opa file1.opa" (directly without using 'make').

If file1 uses module_C from file2.opa, how would I import it?
"import module_C.package_b"?
Once imported, I can call its members "package_b.member1()" from within file1.opa?
(this doesnt seem to work).

interestingly I've been looking for documentation on this online, but its nowhere to be found. The new Opa book too has no answers. I want to know how to do this without using the 'make' facilities, instead do it by hand. This way I can integrated Opa more cleanly into my build system.

I appreciate any guidance :), thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define dependencies of source files with packages and imports using an external file included directly by Opa (no need for `make`) with command:

```
opa --conf opa.conf --conf-opa-files
```

Syntax of the file (`opa.conf` in above example) is to be guessed from the `opa create` command. It looks like:

```
your.package.name:
    import included.package.name
    import another.package.to.be.included
    path/to/the/file.opa
```